# How can I do this Input as a Dropdown button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

How can I do this Input as a Dropdown button in bootstrap

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="user_type">Tipi userit</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="user_type" name="user_type" type="text" placeholder="Tipi i Userit Admin/Editor/User" class="form-control input-md" value="{{ old('user_type') }}" required> 
    @if ($errors->has('user_type'))
      <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('user_type') }}</strong>
      </span> 
    @endif
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you looking for? just a dropdown with the values `Admin`, `Editor` or `User`?

Comment: Yes with those values

Comment: Check out the bootstrap documentation. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/, I know when I was first trying to implement a drop down, I didn't include a link to JQuery or popper.js so it didn't work.

Comment: <select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>